# what does final mean in Groovy

Tags: groovy, final

If you run the following code in the Groovy console it prints "8"

```
class F {

  private final Integer val = 2

  def set(v) {val = v}

  def print() {println val}
}

def f = new F()
f.set(8)
f.print()
```

In Java this code wouldn't compile because you can't assign a `final` reference after the constructor has run. I know that for properties, `final` indicates that the property can't be changed *outside* the class, but what does it mean to mark a private field `final`?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this might be a Groovy bug:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1628
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2752

I wouldn't think that `val` should be assignable after initialization.